# Doubt with array in solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, arrays

I having doubt that I already Declared that array by using that i can insert value Why i cab assign New array object and then i need to insert the values so can some one explain that properly??

```
function getEvens() pure external returns(uint[] memory) {
  uint[] memory evens = new uint[](5);
  // Keep track of the index in the new array:
  uint counter = 0;
  // Iterate 1 through 10 with a for loop:
  for (uint i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    // If `i` is even...
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      // Add it to our array
      evens[counter] = i;
      // Increment counter to the next empty index in `evens`:
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return evens;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain better your question?

Comment: Where in c you can assign array length by while declaring like ```int i[3] = {value}; ```. But in solidity why we are creating new array object and declaring array length  ``` new uint[](5); ``` .